# Creating a Loop to streamline this HTML and CSS code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code which produces a dropdown effect on clicking a button. Each of the seven divs drops down in  increasing increments of 50px. I'm looking to see if there is a more streamlined way of achieving the same effect by possibly looping a function to drop each susbsequent div in 50px increments instead of having to call so many functions:

HTML

```
<button id="click_btn_one" onclick="dropSeven('divSeven'), dropSix('divSix'), dropFive('divFive'), dropFour('divFour'), dropThree('divThree'), dropTwo('divTwo'), dropOne('divOne')">Click here</button>

<div id="divSeven">This is div seven</div>
<div id="divSix">This is div six</div>
<div id="divFive">This is div five</div>
<div id="divFour">This is div four</div>
<div id="divThree">This is div three</div>
<div id="divTwo">This is div two</div>
<div id="divOne">This is div one</div>
```

CSS

```
#divSeven {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; opacity:0; height:50px; width:200px; background:#000; color:#fff}    
#divSix {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; opacity:0; height:50px; width:200px; background:#111; color:#fff}
#divFive {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; opacity:0; height:50px; width:200px; background:#222; color:#fff}
#divFour {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; opacity:0; height:50px; width:200px; background:#333; color:#fff}
#divThree {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; opacity:0; height:50px; width:200px; background:#444; color:#fff}
#divTwo {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; opacity:0; height:50px; width:200px; background:#555; color:#fff}
#divOne {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; opacity:0; height:50px; width:200px; background:#666; color:#fff}
```

and JAVASCRIPT

```
function dropSeven(el) {
var seven = document.getElementById(el);
seven.style.transition = "top 0.8s ease-in 0s, opacity 1s ease-in 0s";
seven.style.opacity = "1";
seven.style.top = "350px"
}

function dropSix(el) {
var six = document.getElementById(el);
six.style.transition = "top 0.8s ease-in 0s, opacity 1s ease-in 0s";
six.style.opacity = "1";
six.style.top = "300px"
}

function dropFive(el) {
var five = document.getElementById(el);
five.style.transition = "top 0.8s ease-in 0s, opacity 1s ease-in 0s";
five.style.opacity = "1";
five.style.top = "250px"
}

function dropFour(el) {
var four = document.getElementById(el);
four.style.transition = "top 0.8s ease-in 0s, opacity 1s ease-in 0s";
four.style.opacity = "1";
four.style.top = "200px"
}

function dropThree(el) {
var three = document.getElementById(el);
three.style.transition = "top 0.8s ease-in 0s, opacity 1s ease-in 0s";
three.style.opacity = "1";
three.style.top = "150px"
}

function dropTwo(el) {
var two = document.getElementById(el);
two.style.transition = "top 0.8s ease-in 0s, opacity 1s ease-in 0s";
two.style.opacity = "1";
two.style.top = "100px";
}

function dropOne(el) {
var one = document.getElementById(el);
one.style.transition = "top 0.8s ease-in 0s, opacity 1s ease-in 0s";
one.style.opacity = "1";
one.style.top = "50px"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider writing your functions as:

```
function drop(offset, id) {
  var four = document.getElementById(id);
  four.style.transition = "top 0.8s ease-in 0s, opacity 1s ease-in 0s";
  four.style.opacity = "1";
  four.style.top = offset + "px"
}
```

Then you can make a function to drop all:

```
function dropAll() {
  ['divOne', 'divTwo', ..., 'divSeven'].forEach(function(id, index) {
    var offset = index * 50 + 50;
    drop(offset, id);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a lot of inline style to your elements during the animation.

Isn't it easier to write CSS like that:

```
#divSeven {
    position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; opacity:0; height:50px; width:200px; background:#000; color:#fff;
}    

#divSeven[dropped=true] {
    transition: top 0.8s ease-in 0s, opacity 1s ease-in 0s; opacity:1;
}
```

and javascript as andlrc showed you

```
function drop(offset, id) {
    var four = document.getElementById(id);
    four.setAttribute('dropped','true');
    four.style.top = offset + "px"
}

dropAll() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alot of ways to do it. I would use css more and use a loop to go through the elements

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/6agzadto/

```
<button id="click_btn_one" onclick="drop()">Click here</button>

<div id="divSeven" data-dropdown class='fade'>This is div seven</div>
<div id="divSix" data-dropdown class='fade'>This is div six</div>
<div id="divFive" data-dropdown class='fade'>This is div five</div>
<div id="divFour" data-dropdown class='fade'>This is div four</div>
<div id="divThree" data-dropdown class='fade'>This is div three</div>
<div id="divTwo" data-dropdown class='fade'>This is div two</div>
<div id="divOne" data-dropdown class='fade'>This is div one</div>

function drop(){
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dropdown]');
  var offset = 50;
  for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].className = 'fade in';
    elems[i].style.top = (offset * i) + 'px';
  }
}

#divSeven {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; height:50px; width:200px; background:#000; color:#fff}    
#divSix {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; height:50px; width:200px; background:#111; color:#fff}
#divFive {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; height:50px; width:200px; background:#222; color:#fff}
#divFour {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; height:50px; width:200px; background:#333; color:#fff}
#divThree {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; height:50px; width:200px; background:#444; color:#fff}
#divTwo {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; height:50px; width:200px; background:#555; color:#fff}
#divOne {position:absolute; top:-100px; left:0px; height:50px; width:200px; background:#666; color:#fff}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: top 0.8s ease-in 0s, opacity 1s ease-in 0s;
}
.fade.in {
  opacity: 1;
}
```